# Ballot RPC message

Tags: voting, operation

How are the last 3 fields (period, proposal, ballot) interpreted in the [Ballot message](https://tezos.gitlab.io/mainnet/api/p2p.html#ballot-tag-6)? How is the vote encoded into the last byte?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Period is a 32-bit integer, the current period is 10 so you'd encode this as:

```
0000000a
```

Proposal is just the hext bytes of the unencoded proposal hash, so you would b58cdecode the proposal hash and convert that to hex. For `Pt24m4xiPbLDhVgVfABUjirbmda3yohdN82Sp9FeuAXJ4eV9otd` you would do:

```
eztz.utility.buf2hex(eztz.utility.b58cdecode("Pt24m4xiPbLDhVgVfABUjirbmda3yohdN82Sp9FeuAXJ4eV9otd", new Uint8Array([2, 170])))
// ab22e46e7872aa13e366e455bb4f5dbede856ab0864e1da7e122554579ee71f8
```

Finally ballot, is either 00 for Yay/Yea, 01 for Nay, 02 for pass. So, if you want to vote yay for proposal Pt24m4xiPbLDhVgVfABUjirbmda3yohdN82Sp9FeuAXJ4eV9otd The last 37 bytes (3 fields) of the operation would be:

```
0000000aab22e46e7872aa13e366e455bb4f5dbede856ab0864e1da7e122554579ee71f800
```